# Powershell - setting AppFabric Persistence provider and Workflow Management service account

Tags: powershell, appfabric

I am trying to set up AppFabric on a Windows 2008 R2 machine using powershell. I have been able to set up a database on a separate SQL machine and set the administrators, readers and users using the `Initialize-ASPersistenceSqlDatabase` command, however, after running that command, I can look at the configuration wizard for AppFabric and it still shows that Persistence is not configured and the default settings for the "AppFabric Workflow Management service account" (NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE) and the "Persistence provider" ("Select a provider") are still present.

Is there a way to set the "AppFabric Workflow Management service account" and the "Persistence provider" so that it uses a service account of my choice and the sqlStoreProvider respectively? And is there something else I need to do to start Persistence?

Should these things be set up before I run the `Initialize-ASPersistenceSqlDatabase`?

Thanks in advance